# how to uninstall (or fix) R-devel?

Tags: r

I install the R-devel about a year ago and today I wanted to update to the current version. I installed and updated using instructions from here: http://singmann.org/installing-r-devel-on-linux/

However, I am getting the following error messages. Any help please?

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘methods’:
package ‘methods’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version

R Under development (unstable) (2018-04-17 r74612) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: @Anonymouscoward: ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an unfortunate problem with using a -devel version of anything. Your dependencies and in this case many packages, are going to have to reinstalled when these conflicts occur. Since this is a base package, you may be better off just removing R, and recompiling it, however, I'd start off just by removing the base libraries and reinstalling them. I haven't used the development version, but I'd say if that doesn't work, scrap it and start over.

This should remove r-base and the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove r-base-core
```

It should remove these, in case you want to do any individually.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base-dev
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base-core
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base-recommended
```

If this didn't work:

```
bash R-devel
update.packages(ask=FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong. Aside from a repo issue.

Comment: Thanks! All the best!